# How can you set up Qualtrics Slider survey to show a preference between two options?

Tags: slider, survey, qualtrics

I'm trying to make a survey in Qualtrics that measures personality by noting preference between two options. How can I set this up in Qualtrics? It seems like it only give you one prompt and then rate that prompt.  I need something that looks like this

working independently I-----------------------|-------------------I  working in a group

Answer (score 1):

The closest Qualtrics question type to what you are looking for is a [Bipolar Matrix](http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/basic-building/editing-questions/question-types-guide/matrix-table/). It is the same concept, except it uses radio buttons instead of a slider.

Answer (score 0):

I asked pretty much the same question and wound up figuring out a way to do this.

You first set your question minimum response to -10 and your maximum response to 10 (thus zero would be no preference when you get the data).

Then set your labels like my StackOverflow question:
[Label to right of question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584245/add-label-to-the-right-of-the-qualtrics-slider/37604781#37604781)

The end result in your case was this:
[image]