# Add label to the right of the qualtrics slider?

Tags: javascript, css, slider, qualtrics

In my qualtrics survey I have a horizontal slider that I want to put a label to the right of the actual slider.

I assume this is a relatively simple CSS fix but I have not been able to properly figure out how qualtrics/CSS works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up figuring it out.

With the Slider styled question you:

1. Click on *Choices* text to edit the text question
2. Go to the *Rich Content Editor*
3. Paste the following code snippet (edit the text appropriately)

   ```
    <p>
       <span style="float: right">On Right</span> 
       <span style="float: left">On Left</span>
    </p>
   ```

A bit of an odd hack but it works!